# How can I add a user to my friends array in my User schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

On my Facebook clone I'm working on I have a button that sends a friend request.

```
<form action="/requests" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="sender" value="<%= id %>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="<%= receiverUserId %>" />
  <button type="submit">Send Friend Request</button>
</form>
```

I also have a POST request in my routes that sends the friend request. It takes the `_id` value of both users and adds to a `FriendRequest` schema.

Here is the POST request

```
router.post("/requests", (req, res) => {
  const { sender, receiver } = req.body;

  // Create a new FriendRequest instance
  const newRequest = new FriendRequest({
    sender,
    receiver,
  });

  // Save the friend request to the database
  newRequest
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      // Redirect to a success page or send a response indicating success
      res.status(204).send();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the error appropriately
      res.status(500).send("Error sending friend request");
    });
});
```

And here is the `FriendRequest` schema

```
const friendRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sender: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  receiver: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["pending", "accepted", "rejected"],
    default: "pending",
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

Under the `/:user/friends` route users can either accept or reject the friend request.

```
router.post("/requests/:id/accept", async (req, res) => {
  const request = await FriendRequest.findById(req.params.id);
  request.status = "accepted";
  await request.save();
  res.redirect("/requests");
});

router.post("/requests/:id/reject", async (req, res) => {
  const request = await FriendRequest.findById(req.params.id);
  request.status = "rejected";
  await request.save();
  res.redirect("/requests");
});
```

I also have a User schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  password: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  profilePictureURL: String,
  friends: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});
```

**What I'm trying to do**

What I'm trying to do is have it so when a user accepts a friend request, their information gets added to the other persons `friends` object inside their `User` schema and vice versa. Right now only the friend request is accepted inside the `FriendRequest` schema but the `friends` object inside both `User` schemas isn't updating to show their new friend and when I check my database after accepting a friend request, the `friends` object still shows an empty array. I'm struggling with figuring out exactly how I can accomplish adding an accepted friend to the `User` schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need not take the user id from both the user, because, the user sending the friend request is already authenticated, and you must have the user id of the authenticated user without needing to fetch it via form. Also, if you are fetching the sender id from the frontend, one can easily hack into the form via dev tools and edit the html to have some random sender id that may not belong to authenticated user.

```html
<form action="/requests" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="<%= receiverUserId %>" />
  <button type="submit">Send Friend Request</button>
</form>
```

Now, at the post request handler, instead of getting sender id from req.body, enter the value from the already authenticated user. I assume you have already created a middleware for checking authentication.

```js
router.post("/requests", (req, res) => {
  const { receiver } = req.body;

  // Create a new FriendRequest instance
  const newRequest = new FriendRequest({
    sender: req.user._id,
    receiver,
  });

  // Save the friend request to the database
  newRequest
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      // Redirect to a success page or send a response indicating success
      res.status(204).send();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the error appropriately
      res.status(500).send("Error sending friend request");
    });
});
```

One more suggestion, instead of creating a new FriendRequest instance, you can use this syntax instead, which is a better practice

```js
FriendRequest.create({
      sender: req.user._id,
      receiver
    }).then(() => {
      // Redirect to a success page or send a response indicating success
      res.status(204).send();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the error appropriately
      res.status(500).send("Error sending friend request");
    });
```

Now coming to the actual question of updating the friends array in user schema, I dont think having an extra array explicitly is necessary.

Since you have senderID in FriendRequest schema, that is the logged in user's id, and also you have the status in the same, if you want to get a list of all friends, you just need to query it accordingly on FriendRequest collection.

```js
FriendRequest
  .find({sender: req.user._id, status: 'accepted'})
  .then((listOfFriends)=>{
    console.log(listofFriends);
  })
  .catch((e)=>{
    // handle error
  })
```

If you still want to explicitly have a separate array in user schema, you need to add the receiver id in that array when the request is accepted.

```js
router.post("/requests/:id/accept", async (req, res) => {
  const request = await FriendRequest.findById(req.params.id);
  request.status = "accepted";
  await request.save();
  const currentUser = await User.findById(currentUserId)
  currentUser.friends.push(request.receiver);
  await currentUser.save();
  res.redirect("/requests");
});
```

but this is not really a good practice, since you are making changes in two different collection. To implement it correctly you will have to use transactions. Because things may go wrong. Suppose your server crashes at the point when the FriendRequest collection change is made but current User is not updated. This might lead to inconsistencies in the database. We have to follow ACID properties.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing response. I'm still learning all this and learning as I go so your comments have helped. One thing I'm still trying to process is the `listOfFriends` thing. Are you suggesting I render `listOfFriends` to the `friends` ejs page and that it will show all accepted friends?

Comment: @Dagger yes ! listOfFriends will show all accepted friends.